# Problemas ao utilizar o iloc pandas

Tags: python, pandas, ipython-notebook

Quero criar um novo `DataFrame` com a seguinte condição:

```
marvel.loc[ marvel['Orientation'] != 'NaN' ]
```

Ou seja, quero que todas as linhas que tenham a coluna `'Orientation'== 'NaN'` sejam excluídas, porém tem algo dando errado. Segue o código:

```
marvel= pd.read_csv('Heroes_Marvel.csv')
marvel.count()
print(marvel.isna().sum())
marvel.columns
orientation=  marvel.loc[(marvel['Orientation']!='NaN')]
```

e quando eu coloco para imprimir o `Orientation` está tudo inclusive os `NaN's`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Devido a forma como `NaN's` são definidos `NaN == NaN -> False`.
Você deve usar a função `pd.IsNull`